# How can I get an old codeigniter project to work in a subdirectory

Tags: codeigniter

First off, I'm not a codeigniter developer, though I've had some exposure to it and MVC in general. I inherited a project where the companies old dev had taken down their codeigniter website and replaced it with a static one page html thing. They did this by (as far as I can tell) just renaming the index.php and putting an index.html in the root.

So... I moved all the codeigniter files to a subdirectory, and renamed the index.php file appropriately

Now the homepage appears, but all internal links are broken with an internal (500) server error.

I've done a couple things to no avail:

- modified the config.php base_url to include the subdir: `$config['base_url']  = "http://". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/subdir/";`
- tried all the options for `$config['uri_protocol']`

Anyone have any ideas?  I really just need to recover the data from the site, which I can do manually just by looking in the database and some other stuff coded directly into the views - but I'd rather just get the old site running in the subdirectory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `$config['index_page'] = '';` ?

Is the server running Apache? If so, what about the `.htaccess` rules? If so, you may need to add a RewriteBase rule, like so:

```
RewriteBase /subdir/
```

We're going off the assumption that the old dev used `anchor()`, `base_url()`, and/or `site_url()` correctly. If they hard-coded the links (which you shouldn't do with CI), then you'd have to write `.htaccess` rules to rewrite them to the new sub directory or edit the controllers/views that might be generating such links.

Comment: do you think its worth me going through that config.php stuff again after this edit?

Comment: Did you test it before putting it in the subdirectory?

Comment: No, I didn't want it to affect the current live page. But you're right to question this.  I realize my approach was flawed, and I am able to access the original site (which is all I need) by just referencing the pages by `site.com/index-.php/pagename`

Comment: Giving you the check, since you got me thinking in the right direction.

Comment: My questioning was more to stave off needless experimentation, that is to say, troubleshooting a problem that might not even really exist (like if the site didn't work to begin with). Getting CodeIgniter to work in a sub directory shouldn't be very hard... there's probably just a single configuration item that's incorrect.

Comment: I agree. Still not sure what was really stopping it from working as I was trying it, but I should've taken the simple route first.  I think the original devs were kinda hacks ( as am I ;-) ) so who knows where the problem was.